# Continuous Kelly Criteria application

Tags: asset-allocation, kelly-criterion

I am exploring the use of the Kelly Criterion for an institutional portfolio, namely a pension fund.

For a continuous outcome process, the Kelly Optimal Proportion to invest into the risky asset at each time step (say, annually) would effectively be the Sharpe Ratio over that time step.

For example, for a Pension fund with:

a) Expected Portfolio Returns of 4% above the risk-free rate of 4% (i.e. 8% total return)

b) A risk of 8% (Note that all of these numbers are annualised)

The Kelly Optimal bet at each time step would be 4%/8% = 0.5. In other words, 50% of the portfolio will be allocated to the risky component, and the other 50% will be allocated to cash.

And this Kelly Optimal bet would, while it doesn't maximise the expected growth rate over 1 time step, theoretically it maximises the expected growth rate over many time periods (say 30 years).

Is this intuition correct?

Comment: The Sharpe Ratio is $\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$ The Kelly Ratio is $\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma^2}$. Notice the difference.

Comment: The wikipedia page on the Kelly Criterion explains this well. It  includes the step for deriving the formula.